# Extract comments from .docx file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, ms-word

does anyone know how to extract comments from .docx file using python.

i got a solution from internet. it works perfectly by paragraph, but i need this by line based or extract the comments by each word.

[image: sample.docx]

```
from docx import Document
from lxml import etree
import zipfile

ooXMLns = {'w':'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'}

#Function to extract all the comments of document(Same as accepted answer)
#Returns a dictionary with comment id as key and comment string as value

def get_document_comments(docxFileName):
    comments_dict={}
    docxZip = zipfile.ZipFile(docxFileName)
    commentsXML = docxZip.read('word/comments.xml')
    et = etree.XML(commentsXML)
    comments = et.xpath('//w:comment',namespaces=ooXMLns)
    for c in comments:
        comment=c.xpath('string(.)',namespaces=ooXMLns)
        comment_id=c.xpath('@w:id',namespaces=ooXMLns)[0]
        comments_dict[comment_id]=comment
    return comments_dict

#Function to fetch all the comments in a paragraph
def paragraph_comments(paragraph,comments_dict):
    comments=[]
    for run in paragraph.runs:
        comment_reference=run._r.xpath("./w:commentReference")
        if comment_reference:
            comment_id=comment_reference[0].xpath('@w:id',namespaces=ooXMLns)[0]
            comment=comments_dict[comment_id]
            comments.append(comment)
    return comments

#Function to fetch all comments with their referenced paragraph
#This will return list like this [{'Paragraph text': [comment 1,comment 2]}

def comments_with_reference_paragraph(docxFileName):
    document = Document(docxFileName)
    comments_dict=get_document_comments(docxFileName)
    comments_with_their_reference_paragraph=[]
    for paragraph in document.paragraphs:  
        if comments_dict: 
            comments=paragraph_comments(paragraph,comments_dict)  
            if comments:
                comments_with_their_reference_paragraph.append({paragraph.text: comments})
    return comments_with_their_reference_paragraph

if __name__=="__main__":
    document="sample.docx"  #filepath for the input document
    print(comments_with_reference_paragraph(document))
```

[image: output for the above code]

Expecting output:

```
{
"word1":{"comment1":{"line-no":1,"author":"author1"}},
                     {"comment2":{"line-no":2,"author":"author2"}},
 "word2":{"comment3":{"line-no":3,"author":"author3"}}
}
```

or

```
{"word1":["comment1,"comment2"],"word2":["comment3"]}
```

Comment: Your example is hard to reproduce locally. You could maybe modify it so that the document is a reference document that anyone can download - so that members can try your code ? Also, what is the outcome of your current code ? This is not clear. Finally please format your python code with lines breaks for readability

Comment: @smarie  edited the code added the screen shots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally i got a responsive code**

```
import os,zipfile
from lxml import etree
import aspose.words as aw

ooXMLns = {'w':'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'}
def comment(doc):
    comments_dict = {}
    comments_of_dict = {}
    author_dict = {}
    date_dict = {}
    # file name and file extension
    filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(doc)
    # if docx, then extract comment
    if file_extension == '.docx':
        docx = doc
    # if doc then convert to docx
    elif file_extension == '.doc':
        fileNames = [doc]
        output = aw.Document()
        output.remove_all_children()
        for fileName in fileNames:
            input = aw.Document(fileName)
            output.append_document(input, aw.ImportFormatMode.KEEP_SOURCE_FORMATTING)
        # convert doc to docx and save filename.docx
        output.save(filename+".docx")
        docx = filename+".docx"

    # docx file to xml file,xml file contains comments.xml and document.xml
    docx_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(docx)
    # retrieve comments from word/comment.xml
    comments_xml = docx_zip.read('word/comments.xml')
    # retrieve commeted word from word/document.xml
    comments_of_xml = docx_zip.read('word/document.xml')
    et_comments = etree.XML(comments_xml)
    et_comments_of = etree.XML(comments_of_xml)
    comments = et_comments.xpath('//w:comment', namespaces=ooXMLns)
    comments_of = et_comments_of.xpath('//w:commentRangeStart', namespaces=ooXMLns)
    # retrieving comments and store in comment_dict
    for c in comments:
        # retrieving comment and sotre in comment obj
        comment = c.xpath('string(.)', namespaces=ooXMLns)
        # retrieve id and store in comment_id
        comment_id = c.xpath('@w:id', namespaces=ooXMLns)[0]
        # mapping comment under particular id
        comments_dict[comment_id] = comment
        # retrieving author detials and mapping under the id
        author_dict[comment_id] = c.xpath('@w:author', namespaces=ooXMLns)[0]
        # retrieving commented date and mapping under the id
        date_dict[comment_id] = c.xpath('@w:date', namespaces=ooXMLns)[0]
    # retrieving commented words and store in comments_of
    for c in comments_of:
        # retrieve id and store in comments_of_id
        comments_of_id = c.xpath('@w:id', namespaces=ooXMLns)[0]
        # in xml file, commented word is placed under the CommentRangeStart and CommentRangeEnd with id
        parts = et_comments_of.xpath("//w:r[preceding-sibling::w:commentRangeStart[@w:id=" + comments_of_id + "] and following-sibling::w:commentRangeEnd[@w:id=" + comments_of_id + "]]",namespaces=ooXMLns)
        comment_of = ''
        # retrieving  
        for part in parts:
            comment_of += part.xpath('string(.)', namespaces=ooXMLns)
            comments_of_dict[comments_of_id] = comment_of
        
    data = []
    for k in comments_of_dict.keys() & comments_dict.keys() & author_dict.keys() & date_dict.keys():
        # fetching datas under same key and append in list
        data.append({"comment": 
comments_dict[k],"text_selected":comments_of_dict[k],"commented_on" : date_dict[k]})
    return data

doc = "document.doc"
data = comment(doc)

print(data)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Use bayoo-docx instead of python-docx:
pip install bayoo-docx